# How to make an insert with a combination of a select and passed parameters in a stored function

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have two tables, e.g.:

```
    CREATE TABLE table_1
    (
        one_column   INTEGER,
        two_column   INTEGER,
        three_column INTEGER
);

    CREATE TABLE table_2
    (
        id        SERIAL,
        column_1  INTEGER,
        column_2  INTEGER,
        column_3  INTEGER,
        name      TEXT,
        step      INTEGER
);
```

I have a stored function which receives a number of parameters. Within the function, I need to `INSERT` a row into a table using a (dynamic?) combination of the results from a `SELECT` and two of the function parameters. Currently I've got something similar to the following pseudo-code...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_p (
    p_id       INTEGER,
    p_name     TEXT    DEFAULT '',
    p_step     INTEGER DEFAULT NULL
    )
RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table_2 (
        column_1,
        column_2,
        column_3,
        p_name,
        p_step
        )
        SELECT
            one_column,
            two_column,
            three_column
            FROM table_1
            WHERE id = p_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Should the INSERT be more like this?

```
    INSERT INTO table_2 (
        column_1,
        column_2,
        column_3,
        name,
        step
        )
        (SELECT
            one_column,
            two_column,
            three_column
            FROM table_1
            WHERE id = p_id),
        p_name,
        p_step;
```

Comment: aren't `p_name` and `p_step` supposed to be values and therefore should appear in the `SELECT` bellow the `INSERT`?

Comment: I did think that, since this would be trying to define the column names with what's been passed to the function. But I'm not sure how to add them as values into the `INSERT`

Comment: ah ok, I got it. You want to dynamically build the insert statement..

Comment: Yes, that would be a better way of describing this. I'll use your words in the description. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `format` to create the insert statement. Also, you problably want a procedure, e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE function_p (
    p_name TEXT DEFAULT '',
    p_step INT DEFAULT NULL
    )
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('
    INSERT INTO table_2 (column_1,column_2,column_3,name,step)
    SELECT one_column, two_column,three_column,%L,%s
    FROM table_1',p_name,p_step);   
END;
$$
```

Keep in mind that the columns number (and types) used in the `INSERT` statement has to match with those coming from the `SELECT`.

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=32f96e1c69702d14001e2b4634c8e7a6)

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give this a go

Comment: I think this is slightly wrong, since the `table_2`  has columns, say `column_1, column_2, column_3, name, step`. So I use the `SELECT` for the first three columns and the parameters for the last two

Comment: @fluffy_mart you mean both `table_1` and `table_2` have the columns passed by the variables?

Comment: I've updated the description to include pseudo-code table descriptions. Sorry I missed this out until now

Comment: It may not be obvious from the above, but there's stuff in the function which I left out to simplify this. E.g. there would be a `WHERE` clause for `table_1` to match an `id` column to a `p_id` function parameter, etc

Comment: @fluffy_mart check my last edit (specially the fiddle)

Comment: One last thing: My `SELECT` contains a `generate_series(now(), now()+a_bit, INTERVAL '1 day')`. How do I 'escape' the apostrophes? Or do I use double apostrophes `''1 day''`? Or can I use double quotes around the `format()` first argument?

Comment: @fluffy_mart that's a different question. But try to escape with two single quotes instead of one `'` -> `''`

Comment: @fluffy_mart of if you prefer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=44a45b11282e2bd966b1e5bc5ea8c00a or https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a753f5b141f8a5b025890e487e6fb52e

Comment: Yes, it would be fiddle #2. Thanks for all your help with this.